# Errors when trying to install adaptive theme on D8 from backend GUI method

Tags: 8, theming

When I try to install the *Adaptive Theme* for Drupal 8 on https://simplytest.me/, I get the following error on /core/autorize.php.

> drupal 8.2.0-rc1
>     Update manager
>     Error message
>     Installation failed! See the log below for more information.
>
> adaptivetheme
>
> Error installing/updating
>       File Transfer failed, reason: Cannot copy /home/r1rkn/www/tmp/update-extraction-3b2e9e06/adaptivetheme/Gemfile.lock to /home/r1rkn/www/themes/adaptivetheme/Gemfile.lock.

This is for the latest Drupal 8 development snapshot version.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you not install it on your machine or server?

Comment: Same thing, showing as installing on localhost, no error displayed, but not installed

Comment: I also extracted the file physically in the themes folder, not showing up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing is you don't install it.

All you have to do is make sure adaptivetheme is somewhere in the /themes/ directory.

Then download and install the [AT Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/at_tools) module and it's AT Theme Generator sub-module, then create a sub-theme via the UI (a tab in the Appearance section). The at_core base theme will install automatically when you enable your sub-theme.

Also, this theme will never show up on the Appearance page, it's hidden deliberately, because it's just a collection of scripts and libraries that support features in sub-themes. It's never intended to be interacted with via a UI, or be set as default etc.

Comment: Thank you, and I can see that installation instructions are on the bottom...it would be nice if they put in red or bold right at the top (THIS IS NOT A STANDARD THEME -- Read instructions below)...I mean, it is called A THEME after all...how can a user know? Drupal is made of modules, themes and libraries...! I simply followed standard backend GUI theme procedure..!

Comment: A user would know by reading the documentation, which is a standard practice for any theme, module or profile. There is no such thing as a "standard theme", just as there is no such thing as a "standard module".